# Check for previously found badblocks on a drive without re-running all of badblocks?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, bad-blocks

I ran badblocks on a couple of drives for 48 hours. One drive had lots of badblocks whereas the other was clean. I then physically took out the drives from the computer and accidentally mixed them up. Now I want to find which of the two drives is the one with badblocks.

Is there a way to quickly check a drive for a previous run of badblocks?

(Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Note for future: if you're going to put identical drives in any computer, use a sharpie to label them… just in case.

Comment: Do you (still) have the output file from `badblocks -o` that detected lots of badblocks?

Comment: @Tetsujin I want to add to mark especially drives that showed errors. This prevents you from using them in critical applications in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to quickly check a drive for a previous run of badblocks?

No. But this is not your question as you said:

> Now I want to find which of the two drives is the one with badblocks.

Assuming that you were running badblocks in a non-destructive manner
any unreadable block reflects one or more unreadable sectors on firmware level.
When reading the SMART attributes of that affected disk the sum of known unreadable sectors is stored in the "pending sector count".
By comparing this attribute for both disks you should be able to find the worn one.

If you have run badblocks in a destructive manner though, your firmware would have remapped unwritable sectors to other locations and badblocks may have not been made aware of that.

**Additional background information**

The firmware of your disk is keeping track of unreadable sectors or those that have been remapped. Badblocks are a non-fractional multiple of the logical sector size of your drive.

The information from badblocks is known to the firmware of your drive as well except for the fact that the firmware is organized sector-oriented whereas badblocks operates in multiples of that.

So the same problem is treated at two different locations (firmware vs badblocks command).

Operating systems use disk space in units of "blocks" (linux terminology) or "clusters" (Windows terminology).

The badblocks have a size of a non-fractional multiple of the logical sector size (a multiple of 1 is allowed so block size would be equal to sector size).